# Instance list of object in animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I want to know if there is anyway I can make instances of a list of objects.And get a list of the new objects.I just want a single instance no more.

I tried using object instancer inside a loop but it give me an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible with some trickery.

At first you have to create multiple instances using the same source object in one Object Instancer node. Then you can use the Copy Object Data node to copy the object data (e.g. the mesh) from one object to another.

[image]

I activated "Use 'Instance' as Output" so that the 'Instance List' also becomes an output of the Invoke Subprogram node.